# blank page ionic2 after build

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

By means of following Commands:

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
```

I added platform & Built APK file But I faced blank screen while running the app on phone. Software works properly in `ionic serve`
and there isn't any error while debugging.
I also had problem with ionic's suggested app

```
ionic start --v2 myApp sidemenu
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: A javascript error could be the case I believe. Try checking the console with something like [Chrome Remote Debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) to see if anything can help there.

Comment: This error is  showed while checking by console:"WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Answer (score 1):

Add this preferences in your "config.xml" file, in the root of your project:

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="20000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, with this solution, problem doesn't solve

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that you have up to date versions of npm and node.

Then make sure that you have the latest version of Ionic (2.2)

To do this you should update your package.json file ..

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
}
```

Then delete your node_modules directory and then run:

npm install (or maybe sudo npm install)

This should update everything and hopefully solve the issue